# HAProxy use different backend if first backend returns http response with 404 status code

Tags: haproxy

Can HAProxy use another backend in case the first (roundrobin selected) backend for current HTTP Request returns HTTP 404 Response?

Comment: You can use core.register_fetches() function that comes with default haproxy-lua integration. 
In frontend configuration, you need to put entry like
use_backend %[lua.choose_backend]
Where choose_backend will be the name of the register_fetches functions.
For example,
core.register_fetches("choose_backend", { "http-req" }, function(txn)
   if code == 200 then
      return 'a'
   else
      return 'b'
   end
end)

I also find this link useful please have a look: https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2016/5/27/selecting-a-haproxy-backend-using-lua.html